# Flutter application has error on creation

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

I am running Flutter for the first time on Android Studio, and my project has errors upon creation. I've already added two emulators, but they won't show up when I try to run the application. I haven't changed a single thing, the project gets created like this.

[Project is created like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOtIw.png)

[I have two emulators added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpXWV.png)

[but no emulators show up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejGFq.png)

I've already tried

```
flutter config --android-sdk C:\...\AppData\Android\Sdk
```

When I run `flutter doctor` it says everything is fine:

[`flutter doctor`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htEnF.png)

[`flutter doctor -v`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MuVCt.png)

I don't know what to do as I can't figure out what's wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test this solution. It worked for me:

1. Go to **Project structure** (`Ctrl+Shift+Alt+S` on Windows)
2. Specify a Project SDK:

[image: Screen]

Then, if an amulator is running it will be displayed.